# Unclear pin connections for BNC connectors on PCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, bnc

I want to use the following BNC connector on the PCB I am designing: https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Amphenol-RF/031-5493-1010?qs=py4qCovljJ%2FMGk8N0v0eQw%3D%3D

The component has 4-pins and the data sheet does not make it clear which pin to connect to my signal or ground. I am also confused as to what the MH pins are.[image]

Comment: The terminal connecting to the metal part is by default, ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pin physically in the center (2) is the signal pin (center of the BNC). The other pin is Ground.

The MH snap-in pins are for 2mm diameter mounting holes, they are electrically isolated from the rest of the connector in this particular model so you can leave them floating or ground them as you prefer.

That symbol is really terrible, and should be improved to at least show which pin is which, lest an expensive error occur.

Answer (score 3):

MH stands for mounting hole, they do not need to be connected.
The two inner pins are the ground (1) and signal (2). This is backed up by the labeling on the drawing.